# How to perform template manipulation after manual $compile?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to render a list of categories in a webapp I'm developing using AngularJS.

Each category can have an array of `subcategories`.

In order to render them, I created a recursive `category` directive that works like this:

- if the category doesn't have subcategories, render as a complete category.
- if the category has subcategories, render the supercategory as a container for subcategories, and insert and compile the subcategories.

This is the code of the directive:

```
.directive('category', 
  function(WeeklyCalendar, categoryRowsFactory, $compile){
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'new-category-tpl',
      scope: {
        category: '=categoryData'
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        //recursive categories rendering
        if(scope.category.subcategories) {
          $compile('<div ng-repeat="sub in category.subcategories track by sub.id" category category-data="sub"></div>')
          (scope, function(cloned, scope){ elem.append(cloned) })
        }

        /* This works */
        //elem.append('aaa');

        /* This doesn't */
        elem.find('.content').append('aaa');
      }
    };
})
```

Everything working well so far, you can check the result here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/simonedavico/pen/xpcrB?editors=101)

So, each category has `category-row`s that are split in a `header` and a `content`, like this:

```
<div class="category">
    <div class="category-row">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to append some HTML to the div with class `content` from the `link` function. Anyway, using the classic `element.find('.content').append('string')` won't work, as `find` returns no result. (**even if jQuery is included**). Strangely enough, because if you inspect the HTML you can see that each category clearly has a `category-row` children, which contains a `.content` div. Simply appending to `element` works, but it's not enough for me.

By the way, this is the template for a `category`:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="new-category-tpl">
    <div ng-class="{'category multicategory': category.subcategories, 'category single': category.type == 'Single', 'subcategory': category.type == 'Subcategory'}">
      <div ng-if="category.subcategories" class="supercategory">
        <strong>{{category.name}}</strong>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="category.type != 'WithSub'" class="category-row">
        <div class="header">{{category.name}}</div>
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>   
  </script>
```

Nothing fancy, as far as I can see.

I wasted an entire afternoon trying to understand what I'm missing, without success. Maybe you will be smarter/luckier. So, does anyone know why `element.find(..)` doesn't work in that `link` function?

### Update

The solution from ExpertSystem works, up to a point. I am able to `append` in the `$timeout` call, that part is fine. But later I need to access the same element I append in the directive's controller, but the template is still uncompiled and it doesn't work.

Maybe I am using the wrong approach. This is what I am trying to achieve:

- I need to display categories in a calendar;
- These categories can be of three types:

  - Single categories, they have a single row in which I display events;
  - Multi categories, they have many rows in which I display events;
  - Categories with subcategories, they have a row for each subcategory.
- Each row of the category features empty placeholder cells for days without events;
- I created a recursive template that renders a category as a container for subcategories, or as a row made of a `.header` with the category name and a `.content`; The `.content` is simply a empty `div` in the template.
- My idea is that, since the empty placeholder cells don't have to be data-bound to anything, I could insert them in the `link` function by jQuery (since I have to check how many of them have to be inserted, depending on the size of the calendar; I also need to check if I have to append only one row of cells or many rows, depending on the type of category).
- These cells would be useful in placing the events at a later time: the event would ask to the cateogory controller for the position of the right cell, and place itself at the same position by means of `elem.css` or `ng-style`.

This becomes impossible if `element` becomes inaccessible, since I have to place events with absolute positioning and I need to know `top` and `left`. I Here is a short version of what I'm trying to achieve in the end:

```
.directive('category',function(){
   //...usual stuff
   controller: function($scope, $element){
       this.getPosition = function(date) {
           var cellSelector//compute selector for placeholder cell depending on date
           var cell = $element.find(cellSelector);
           return { top: cell.top(), left: cell.left()}
       }
   }
})

.directive('event',function(){
    //...usual stuff
    require: '^category',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, categoryCtrl) {
        var position = categoryCtrl.getPosition(scope.event.date);
        element.css(positiong);
    }
})
```

I am out of ideas. Can someone think of a better way to achieve what I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that `ngIf` (among other directives) removes the template from the DOM and decides what/if to append at a later time (after a few $digest loops).

So at the time you try to access `.content`, the element's innerHTML looks like this:

```
<!-- ngIf: category.subcategories -->
<!-- ngIf: category.type!=='WithSub' -->
```

---

The "safest" to access `.content` once it is rendered is to wrap your code into a `$timeout` callback:

```
$timeout(function () {
    elem.find('.content').text('aaa');
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/9T58z/)**.

Comment: Thank you! But shouldn't the template be already compiled when I call find? At least I thought so... The template should be uncompiled only at `compile` time, right?

Comment: IT can't be compiled at compile time, because you compile it manually from within your linking function (at linking time). So it get's compiled at linking time (and an `ngIf`'s compiled HTML initially looks like this `<!-- ngIf: someProp -->`). There are a few asynchronous operations involved before your HTML looks the way you expect it to.

Comment: Nice to know, I thought that after the call to `$compile` I would have the HTML ready to be used as I wished. Just one more curiosity: how did you find out? Honestly I had no clue in regards to where to look for the problem. Knowing how you did could help me if a similar situation occurs. I'll implement your solution ASAP and accept your answer!

Comment: First of all it helps to have been there a couple of times - it kind of gives you a clue :D Yet your best friend is debugger (or even plain old console.log). If you expect `elem.find('.content')` to return something and still get nothing, the first thing to ask yourself is "What does the content of elem **actually** look like ?". Adding a `console.log(elem.html());` right before `elem.find(...)` gives you the first clue :)

Comment: I implemented the solution, it works. I hope this `$compile` call won't give me more problems. Thank you again!

Comment: As I stated yesterday, the solution works, but not completely: I am able to append the html in the `$timeout`, but I need to retrieve it in the directive's controller (to check its position and return it to a child directive). Obviously, I am not able to retrieve because the element is still not compiled. Wrapping the call to `find` in a `$timeout` in the controller won't work. Do you know how could I solve this? I updated the question with what I am trying to achieve in the end, because maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Don't you lke dudes unaccepting answers just because they realized they had to ask a different question or they want to squiz a second question or different requirements into the original :)

Comment: I'm truly sorry, I thought all morning about this. I honestly don't know if it's another question, the problem is still the same: manipulating the template of a directive inserted dynamically. I need to be able to do it both in the controller and the link function. I am sorry if I did not think about the whole problem when I first posted the question.